# 'node filename.js' command Where is it storing my data?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to connect my AngularJS app to the heroku database. I am following this guide here (http://nodeexamples.com/2012/09/21/connecting-to-a-postgresql-database-from-node-js-using-the-pg-module/) and I got to the very end and it even shows all of the data that I've created using the code "client.query(INSERT INTO...)" but my questions is, where in my actual directory is it storing my data? Even though I've connected via my heroku database's user, password, database, etc It doesn't show up on my heroku database that I connected with, however it is storing it somewhere.

My code in index.js

```
var pg = require('pg');

var client = new pg.Client({
    user: "herokudatabaseusername",
    password: "herokudatabasepassword",
    database: "herokudatabasebasename",
    port: 0000,
    host: "hostname",
    ssl: true
}); 
client.connect();

client.query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table(id integer, name varchar(64), description varchar(1024), type varchar(128), ...etc');
client.query('INSERT INTO table(id, name, description, type, ...etc) values($1, $2, $3, ...etc)', [ 1, 'someinfo', 'moreinfo', ...etc]);

var query = client.query('SELECT id, name, description, type, ...etc, FROM table ORDER BY name');
query.on('row', function (row, result) {
    result.addRow(row);
});
query.on('end', function (result) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result.rows, null, '    '));
    client.end();
});
```

Sample output after I run my 'node index.js' command in the terminal twice

```
[
    {
         "id": 1,
         "name": "...",
         "description": "...",
         "ect": "...",
         "ect": "...",
         ...
         ...
         ...
    },
    {
         "id": 1,
         "name": "...",
         "description": "...",
         "ect": "...",
         "ect": "...",
         ...
         ...
         ...
    }
]
```

So it seems as the data is persisting I'm just not sure where.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code executes a query.  It then iterates through the results, calling `console.log` for each line.

So it doesn't look like your app stores the results anywhere.  It just logs them?

You'll probably see them fly by if you did a `heroku logs --tail`.

By the way, take care if you do plan to store stuff on the file system.  The file system is [ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/how-heroku-works).  So if you want to properly store it, use a backing service (like the database).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think you might be right in that my app is not storing the results anywhere, however, when I run the node command again, the previously added rows are still there, meaning they are storing somewhere just I'm not sure where. Do you know how I could store these results somewhere of my choosing, most preferably into my heroku cloud database. That was my intention from the beginning, to connect my app to Heroku PostgreSQL database.

Comment: Use the database. You're already doing.  See the line: `client.query('INSERT INTO table ... `  Every time you run it, it looks like it will add a line to the table.

Comment: Are you saying that I am already connected to the Heroku PostgreSQL database? How come I can't see it within my Heroku database in Heroku? If my database name is 'mydata' and I click on it and within it (https://postgres.heroku.com/databases/mydata) it doesn't show me any data within it. Does it still mean I am already connected to it? If so how do I see my data?

Comment: Also I checked my logs using `heroku logs -t` and `heroku logs -p postgres -t` (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#monitoring-logging) and I couldn't find anything regarding my data being sent

Comment: Oh my bad I thought you were actually connected to the database. Is that the actual code you're using?   What is your code for connecting to the database?  Check out this guide for what it should look like: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#using-a-postgresql-database